# Accessing value of field within array from JSON data

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-2.7

I am trying to access the value for a field that is part of an array within JSON data. Here is the JSON Data (I :

```
{
"response":
{
"test-item": {
    "id": 125252,
    "code": null,
    "name": "test_1",
    "section_id": 85552653,
    "state": "active",
    "start_date": "2016-10-10 00:00:00",
    "end_date": null,
    "timezone": "US/Pacific",
    "discrepancy_pct": 0,
    "publishers_allowed": "all",
    "campaigns": [
        {
            "id": 85669995691,
            "name": "test_campaign",
            "profile_id": 43562,
            "inventory_type": "direct",
            "state": "active",
            "priority": 5,
        },
        {
            "id": 800099981123,
            "name": "test_campaign_2",
            "profile_id": 12562,
            "inventory_type": "direct",
            "state": "active",
            "priority": 5,
        }
    ]}}}
```

I am only trying to pull the values for the fields "id" which appears in the "campaigns" array. Here is what the section of my code that I am using to accomplish this looks like:

```
url = "https://api.example.com"  

header = {"Authorization": authorization_code}

api_response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

test_response = json.loads(api_response.text)

filtered_campaigns = test_response.get("response", {}).get("test-item", 
{}).get("campaigns", "id")
```

When using this, I get back the entire value for the "campaigns" array instead of just the ids for all of the campaigns. Can anyone help point out what I am doing wrong here? I am still fairly new to Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you can use `api_response.json()` to get the response as a JSON dictionary.

Second, since the value keyed with `campaigns` is a list, you should either use a list comprehension or `map` to collect `id`s:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> test_response = api_response.json()
>>> filtered_campaigns = map(
        itemgetter("id"), 
        test_response.get("response", {}).get("test-item", {}).get("campaigns", []))

[85669995691, 800099981123]
```

Comment: I am not sure how it worked and gave correct result with the missing `)` and without using `.get('campaigns',[])`

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
filtered_campaigns = [x['id'] for x in test_response['response']['test-item']['campaigns']]
```

It's a list comprehension that sets filtered_campaigns equal to a list of IDs.